# PHP regular expression for text with json data

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm looking for a PHP regular expression to match a pattern for multiple set of json data in a text string.

> Paragraph One text
>
> [[{"fid":"28","view_mode":"teaser","fields":{},"type":"media","attributes":{"class":"media-element file-teaser"},"link_text":null}]]
>
> Second Paragraph
>
> [[{"fid":"26","view_mode":"preview","fields":{},"type":"media","attributes":{"class":"file media-element file-preview"},"link_text":"mohan sample.mp4"}]]

Above is the example text with json samples, i want to extract the value of "fid" from each json data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to `json_decode()` this and read the value directly?

Comment: @anubhava `json_decode()` won't work if it's mixed in with other text. He needs the regexp to find just the single JSON object so he can decode it.

Comment: Do you need to be able to match ANY JSON, or just something very similar to what you've posted? I suspect there's no easy regexp to match JSON in general, because of the recursion and escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\[\[{(?:(?!\]\])[\s\S])*"fid":"\K\d+
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/10

```
$re = "/\\[\\[{(?:(?!\\]\\])[\\s\\S])*\"fid\":\"\\K\\d+/mi";
$str = "[[{\"fid\":\"28\",\"view_mode\":\"teaser\",\"fields\":{},\"type\":\"media\",\"attributes\":{\"class\":\"media-element file-teaser\"},\"link_text\":null}]]\n\nSecond Paragraph\n\n[[{\"fid\":\"26\",\"view_mode\":\"preview\",\"fields\":{},\"type\":\"media\",\"attributes\":{\"class\":\"file media-element file-preview\"},\"link_text\":\"mohan sample.mp4\"}]]";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```